# An element is either in a set or not in a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, propositional-calculus

Is there a name for the following obvious fact?

> Given any set $S$ and any object $s$, either $s \in S$ or $s \notin S$.

Comment: It’s an application of the [law of the excluded middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle). (But what if $s$ is Schrödinger’s cat, and $S$ is the set of living cats?)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott apparently, the cat is not a well-formed formula :)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Ha! I am going to sweep all cats into the litterbox for my students.

Comment: Only true in classical logic. Brouwer would not have said it is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [law of the excluded middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle), which is a tautology is classical logic.

$$ \varphi \lor \lnot \varphi \;\;\text{is true for all well-formed formulas $\varphi$} $$